# How write CHECK condition for every element in array in postgreSQL

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql

I don't know how work with loops and arrays in PostgreSQL but i want make table with array which only accepts the given values. 
('Icelandic','English','Polish','Danish','Norwegian','Swedish','French','German','Spanish') 
How write this condition in shorter and prettier form?

```
 CREATE TABLE Test(
        UUID UUID NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY ,
        Name varchar(40) NOT NULL UNIQUE , --
        Languages text[] NOT NULL CHECK (
        Languages[1] IN (
        'Icelandic','English','Polish','Danish','Norwegian',
         'Swedish','French','German','Spanish'
            )
        AND
            Languages[2] IN (
        'Icelandic','English','Polish','Danish','Norwegian',
         'Swedish','French','German','Spanish'
            )
        AND
            Languages[3] IN (
        'Icelandic','English','Polish','Danish','Norwegian',
         'Swedish','French','German','Spanish'
            )
        AND
            Languages[4] IN (
        'Icelandic','English','Polish','Danish','Norwegian',
         'Swedish','French','German','Spanish'
            )
        AND
            Languages[5] IN (
        'Icelandic','English','Polish','Danish','Norwegian',
         'Swedish','French','German','Spanish'
            )     AND
            Languages[5] IN (
        'Icelandic','English','Polish','Danish','Norwegian',
         'Swedish','French','German','Spanish'
            )
        AND
            Languages[6] IN (
        'Icelandic','English','Polish','Danish','Norwegian',
         'Swedish','French','German','Spanish'
            )
        AND
            Languages[7] IN (
        'Icelandic','English','Polish','Danish','Norwegian',
         'Swedish','French','German','Spanish'
            )     AND
            Languages[8] IN (
        'Icelandic','English','Polish','Danish','Norwegian',
         'Swedish','French','German','Spanish'
            )
        AND
            Languages[9] IN (
        'Icelandic','English','Polish','Danish','Norwegian',
         'Swedish','French','German','Spanish'
            ) )
    
    );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A better solution would be to use the `@>` or `<@` operators as described here https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-array.html

```
...CHECK (languages <@ ARRAY['Icelandic','English','Polish','Danish','Norwegian','Swedish','French','German','Spanish'])
```

However I suggest you use the common [two-or-three letter language codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ISO_639-1_codes), instead of the full names. It's just more useful during migrations.

Comment: Thanks for sollution and hint about langues codes ;)